# Datetime on time tag wordpress puts it outside the tag

Tags: tags, seo, date-time, html5, timestamp

I want to use a time tag with the datetime attribute in it... I tried this in **functions.php**:

```
<time class="time" datetime='. the_date('d-m-Y') . '>%3$s '.get_the_time( $d, $post ).'</time>'
```

But instead of putting it in the `time tag`, it outputs the date in the content itself, which is very weird... How can this be solved?

Comment: Why a downvote without a comment? Damn, some people are weird.

Comment: None of the downvotes are mine but I am pretty sure I can tell you why. Hover over the lower arrow. Notice "This question does not show any research effort". Given that the answer is in the Codex, this question is a textbook example of that.

Comment: I understand. Will do it better next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General WordPress rule:

when a function starts with `get`, it will return the value. If it starts with `the`, it echoes the value.

Here, you need [`get_the_date('d-m-Y')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) instead of `the_date('d-m-Y')`.

Comment: Shit, that simple, yet so effective. Thank you Rrikesh!

Answer (score 1):

[`the_date`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) accepts four parameters. The fourth is an `echo` parameter-- false by default.

```
the_date('d-m-Y','','',true); // this will echo
```

Also, be aware that `the_date` and `get_the_date` are not equivalent functions, differing only in that the latter `echo`s and the former does not (by default).

> the_date
>
> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY,
>   the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the
>   first instance of the_date()).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

Whereas...

> get_the_date
>
> Unlike the_date() this tag will always return the date.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date

Additionally, `the_date` has `$before` and `$after` parameters-- the second and third ones-- while `get_the_date` does not.